# How to set a new workflow status property in Sharepoint Designer Workflow 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow

I am trying to set a new workflow status property in the SharePoint Designer Workflow 2010. (refer the screen below)

[image]

I would like to add one more option called Hold in the Drop Down list in SharePoint Designer..

Answer (score 0):

It may be you can only do this using Visual Studio.  I don't think it is possible via Sharepoint Designer.

[This page has details on how to do it in Visual Studio](http://sharepoint.ginni.me/2010/01/setting-workflow-status-to-custom.html), although I haven't tried it yet.  [There is this, too](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/alimaz/archive/2008/02/08/setting-workflow-status-to-custom-value.aspx).